# How to use reduce function to aggregate the data using more than one attribute - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
concatednatedArray.reduce(function (result, o) {
    var unit = o.chargeAmountUnit;
    if (!(unit in result)) {
        result.arr.push(result[unit] = o);
    } else {
        result[unit].chargeAmount += o.chargeAmount;
    }
    return result;
}, { arr: [] }).arr;
```

In the above code i group the data based only on chargeAmountUnit but i need to group it by using both chargeAmountUnit and currencyCode. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you supply some sample data?

Comment: Show us some example input and expected output, please.

Comment: Don't ask a question multiple times (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312706/how-to-aggregate-the-data-based-on-more-than-one-attribute-using-reduce-function) improve your existing one.